# How to set default value of mat-select when data is coming from API?

Tags: angular, angular-material

EXPECTED:

I have a `mat-select` which should display the currently available status of a ticket in a dropdown menu when clicked and on site initalization it should select and display the current status out of that list.

CURRENT STIATION:

Currently it keeps showing me the placeholder text when the site is loaded. If I change the value via code or dropdown menu the value changes which means that everythings works as intended except displaying the initial status

HTML Code fragment:

```
<mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Ticketstatus</mat-label>
        <mat-select #statusSelect [(ngModel)]="displayedTicket.status" [(value)]="displayedTicket.status" (selectionChange)="updateTicketStatus(displayedTicket)">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let status of statusList" [value]="status">
            {{status.statusName}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
```

The object `statusList` contains all available status and shows them in the dropdown menu and `displayedTicket` is the currently displayed ticket including status information.

In my `TypeScript` class I don't have any code referencing the `mat-select`.

Comment: what is your "displayedTicket.status" on initialization.I would start from there.It should be one of the values in statuslist

Comment: the value of displayStatus.status must be `===` to one of the elements of statusList. Is it? See the difference betwee https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1aqkfe?file=app%2Fselect-hint-error-example.ts and https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1aqkfe-d4ryvx?file=app/select-hint-error-example.ts

Comment: I think the problem is that your value of mat-option is status and not status.statusName

Comment: Both JB Nizet and Ashok are right! Instead of assigning it to an element of statusList I just kept the status that go returned from the API in the ticket therefore not fullfilling the === condition.